# Fish Shell: fish_config not setting background color

Tags: macos, terminal, fish

I am pretty new to the fish shell and am having difficulties with configuration on OS X Yosemite.

In particular, I can run fish_config and set foreground colors, but not the background colors.  This is true when using the Mac Terminal app, and also iTerm2.

Is the ability to set the background expected behavior?  And does fish_config play well / interfere with Oh My Fish?  (I currently to not have it installed).

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shell cannot set the background color, only your terminal app can. The background colors in `fish_config` are like a preview.

To set the background color in Terminal.app, go to Preferences->Profiles->Window and set Background. In iTerm2, go to Preferences->Profiles->Colors, and set Background.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I ended up learning that the hard way, and using iTerm for my fish-terminal.

Comment: Can't the running application change the background of the "tiles" with ANSI escape codes? Isn't that what programs such as `vim` do to set the background color and evade the default?